# Is there a consequence to assign a general to an other army stacks?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

I'm doing two wars at the same time. Battlefields are far one from the other.

**I was asking me if there is a malus or a consequence to switch a general from an army stack to an other (that is really far) many time in a short laps of time ?**

I've read on the net (on an unofficial source) that the general will fight as usual, but will be likely to die sooner than expected. Is it right? In this case, I might choose to buy an other general instead of exhausting a really good one.

**EDIT** : I know right there is a risk each time he's fighting to die during the battle. But otherwise, is there other factors that can make him die younger than expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your source is correct, but only because the general will fight in a LOT of battles when used in this way. It's only logical that this results in an increased chance of him getting killed somewhere along the way.

Other than that I fully agree with Laf that there is no reason at all not to switch your good guy around to fight the important battles.

Answer (score 2):

I have not experienced the behavior you are referring to. Switching generals is generally a good idea if you can afford it (strategy-wise). I've done it in virtually every war I've fought, and it saved me a lot of troubles. Your generals will always have a chance to die in every fight they are part of anyway.